# ng-selected inside of ng-repeat not working (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, comparison, angularjs-ng-repeat, html-select

I'm trying to make a comparison of values to "check" an `<option>` tag inside of my `<select>` tag, but can't find a solution...

*This is an administration page, so I already have the {{x.nivel}} value. I just need to mark it as "selected" according to each "inscritos" from `ng-repeat`.

Help :\

```
            <li ng-repeat="x in inscritos | orderBy:'nome'">
                <select>
                    <option ng-selected="(this.value)=={{x.nivel}}" value="Iniciante">Iniciante</option>
                    <option ng-selected="(this.value)=={{x.nivel}}" value="Intermediário">Intermediário</option>
                    <option ng-selected="(this.value)=={{x.nivel}}" value="Avançado">Avançado</option>
                </select>
        </li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `{{}}` in js expression:

```
 <li ng-repeat="x in inscritos | orderBy:'nome'">
    <select>
       <option ng-selected="x.nivel=='Iniciante'" value="Iniciante">Iniciante</option>
       <option ng-selected="x.nivel=='Intermediário'" value="Intermediário">Intermediário</option>
       <option ng-selected="x.nivel=='Avançado'" value="Avançado">Avançado</option>
     </select>
 </li>
```

The double curly brace notation `{{ }}` is used to bind values with html elements. See [templates](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/templates) docs.

Comment: Hey, Lukasz, worked like a charm :) Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm glad that helped :)